# Yii2 disable Bootstrap Js, JQuery and CSS

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii2, yii-extensions

Same as title, i don't want using bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js. I try using:

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
            'css' => [],
        ],
    ],
],
```

It remove bootstrap.css but can't remove bootstrap.js. Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

In `web.php` config file add the following code into components array:

```
'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                'js'=>[]
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

To be more comprehensive:

**in order to disable Css (bootstrap.css):**

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
            'css' => [],
        ],
    ],
],
```

**in order to disable JS (bootstrap.js):**

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
            'js'=>[]
        ],
    ],
],
```

**in order to disable JQuery (jquery.js)**

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
            'js'=>[]
        ],
    ],
],
```

**In order to have all of them disabled:**

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
            'js'=>[]
        ],
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
            'js'=>[]
        ],
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
            'css' => [],
        ],

    ],
],
```

---

**UPDATE**

As **Soju** mentioned in comments, another alternative way would be disabling these files in `AppAsset` class, which is located in `./assets/`, then remove the following lines:

```
public $depends = [
   'yii\web\YiiAsset',              #REMOVE
   'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',  #REMOVE
];
```

Comment: Why does this give me: `Invalid Call – yii\base\InvalidCallException
Setting read-only property: yii\web\Application::assetManager`?

Comment: How would i achieve this in Yii v1.1.15?

Comment: No need to modify assetmanager for this... You juste have to modify app asset bundle...

Comment: Did you read this ? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#defining-asset-bundles

Comment: To disable bootstrap you simply have to remove it from `$depends` in `AppAsset`

Comment: It works, you should remove all bootstrap widget/bundle use from your app.

Comment: Please note:  Afaikt: If we don't want to have Yii 2 to load their Jquery version, removing 'yii\web\YiiAsset' will do nothing. Jquery will still load.

Comment: Make sure your assetManager array in components!@IvoRenkema

Comment: I don't want to load Bootstrap CSS in Yii2. I could'nt found the correct file to paste this update. Can anyone share the path of the config file ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

For anyone that gets "Invalid Call" errors you have to add Ali's answer to 'components' in $config variable in `app/config/web.php` E.g.

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                'js'=>[]
            ],
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                'js'=>[]
            ],
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                'css' => []
            ]
        ]
    ],
    ...
],
```

Comment: This is true only for the basic template

Answer (score 11):

On AppAsset.php file add this:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    // resetting BootstrapAsset to not load own css files
    \Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles['yii\\bootstrap\\BootstrapAsset'] = [
        'css' => [],
        'js' => []
    ];
}
```

Comment: This is a cleaner option, than changing config files and may be used to reset bootstrap from themes

Comment: where do I put that? inside the class AppAsset??

Comment: \Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles['yii\\bootstrap4\\BootstrapAsset'] = [
   'css' => [],
   'js' => []
  ];