# Loading core scripts such as jQuery in Yii 2

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii2

I've been having a hard time trying to figure out how to load `jQuery` or other CORE scripts in `Yii 2`.

In `Yii 1` it seemed this was the way:

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript("jquery"); ?>
```

In Yii 2, $app is a property of Yii, not a method, so the above naturally doesn't work, but changing it to:

```
<?php Yii::$app->clientScript->registerCoreScript("jquery"); ?>
```

produces this error:

```
Getting unknown property: yii\web\Application::clientScript
```

I couldn't find any documentation for Yii 2 about loading core scripts, so I tried the below:

```
<?php $this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . '/js/jquery.min.js', array('position' => $this::POS_HEAD), 'jquery'); ?>
```

Whilst this loads jQuery in the head, a second version of jQuery is also loaded by Yii *when needed* and hence causes conflict errors.

Additionally, I don't want to use Yii's implementation of jQuery, I would prefer to maintain my own and hence that is why I am doing this.

How can I load jQuery and other core files without Yii loading duplicate copies of them when it needs them?

Comment: you may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734385/yii2-disable-bootstrap-js-jquery-and-css/26734892#26734892 and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to disable `Yii2`'s default assets you can refer to this question:

**[Yii2 disable Bootstrap Js, JQuery and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734385/yii2-disable-bootstrap-js-jquery-and-css/26734892#26734892)**

Anyway, `Yii2`'s asset management way is different from `Yii 1.x.x`. First you need to create an `AssetBundle`. As official guide example, create an asset bundle like below in ``:

```
namespace app\assets\YourAssetBundleName;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class YourAssetBundleName extends AssetBundle 
{
public $basePath = '@webroot';
public $baseUrl = '@web';
public $css = [ 
    'path/file.css',//or files 
]; 
public $js=[
     'path/file.js' //or files
];

//if this asset depends on other assets you may populate below array
public $depends = [
];
}
```

Then, to publish them on your views:

```
use app\assets\YourAssetBundleName;
YourAssetBundleName::register($this);
```

Which `$this` refers to current view object.

---

On the other hand, if you need to only register `JS` files into a view, you may use:

```
$this->registerJsFile('path/to/file.js');
```

[yii\web\View::registerJsFile()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJsFile()-detail)

And if you need to only register `CSS` files into a view, you may use:

```
$this->registerCssFile('path/to/file.css');
```

[yii\web\View::registerCssFile()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerCssFile()-detail)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the core jQuery from loading like so:

**config/web.php**

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        // you can override AssetBundle configs here       
         'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
            'sourcePath' => null,
            'js' => [] 
        ],        
    ],
],
```

Comment: Is that the only way to do it? No way similar to Yii 1?