# Yii2 - jQuery working only on remote server

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

Following @AliMasudianPour on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077576/loading-core-scripts-such-as-jquery-in-yii-2/32114310#32114310) instructions I was able to get Jquery working on my dev/prod environment on my **remote server** without problem. However, on my **local server** running on a Mamp. Jquery insistis on not work. I keep getting the errors:

> $ is not defined
>   jQuery is not defined
>   yii is not defined
>   Cannot read property ‘fn’ of undefined

I've compared all *AppAssets* and *Conf* lines on the *Common* and *Frontend* directories between local and remote installation.

Probably I'm skipping some important step. Could someone give me some hint on what could be?

Some snippets from my code:

*frontend/assets/AppAsset.php*

```
<php
namespace frontend\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/main.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js',
    ];
    public $jsOptions = [
        'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD
    ];
    public $depends = [
    ];
}
```

on frontend/config/main.php

inside components:

```
'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                    'js'=>[]
                ],
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                    'css' => []
                ],
                'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                    'sourcePath' => null,
                    'js'=>[]
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

on the layout in view:

```
use frontend\assets\AppAsset;
AppAsset::register($this);
```

by the way, it works for other js scripts, only not to jquery!

Comment: are you sure, you have the correct path? Try to direct access your jquery file

Comment: yes, i've tried with other js scripts and it works fine.

Comment: Did you try doing, view source and clicked those assets?

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of these two pieces of code and now everything works fine.

```
public $js = [
    'js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js',
];




'bundles' => [
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                    'js'=>[]
                ],
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                    'css' => []
                ],
                'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                    'sourcePath' => null,
                    'js'=>[]
                ],
            ],
```

and included

```
public $depends = [
   'yii\web\YiiAsset',
];
```