# Application file re-organization in Yii 2

Tags: yii, yii2, organization, application-structure

I have set up new Yii2 project. Now I want to [reorganize folder structure](http://prntscr.com/8rqoyb) in two folders "public" and "app" (which actually represents the protected files).

All the code from framework goes in "app" folder. In "public" folder I have only one script named "index.php" from where I'm calling the app. The code there looks like the following (I have only modified only the paths from the original "index.php").

**app/index.php**

```
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../app/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../app/config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();

?>
```

This same approach was working in the Yii framework where we got different syntax of the commands. But now in Yii 2 I got the following issue:

[image]

So it seems like all the paths are pointing to the right files (I have check that), but I still got the error. So what I'm missing here? Why the basePath still recognize the "public" folder?

**UPDATE 1:**

After following the comment from @marche and add the following code to the config file:

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'assetManager' => [
        'basePath' => 'my/path/to/assets',
    ],
    ...
],
```

I'm not getting the error with the screen anymore, **but now the content is loaded without any CSS styling and without JS files (they are still pulling URL from the wrong places).**

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734385/yii2-disable-bootstrap-js-jquery-and-css and issue: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5521

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In the "public" folder instead of just having the "index.php" script, I have moved the complete "web" folder from the "protected" folder (where actually all the assets and scripts were located).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the assets directory you need to configure the AssetsManager Component on your config file `web.php`:

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'assetManager' => [
        'basePath' => 'my/path/to/assets',
    ],
    ...
],
```

Comment: OK, I have a progress now.. I'm not getting the error anymore, but now assets and css are not loaded.. should I add something else about them?