# How to add materialize in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, material-design, materialize

I'm trying to add [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) in my Advanced Yii2 Project.

and there is a sample template for this, but i can't even use it in my yii application

http://yii2.themefactory.net/theme/54/material-simple#.ViNmS_krLIU

How can i add materialize css's in my main application?

is there a good tutorial about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy to add materialize framework into your `Yii2` App.

First way (Not suggested):

Copy all needed `CSS` and `JS` files into your public web directory. Then in your `frontend\assets\AppAsset` class add the following lines:

```
public $css = [
    //... another css files
    'css/materialize.min.css'
];


public $js = [
    //... another js files
    'js/materialize.min.js'
];
```

---

Another way would be using Yii2's `Bower`.

> Most `JavaScript/CSS` packages are managed using `Bower` and/or `NPM`, instead of `Composer`. `Yii` uses the `Composer asset plugin` to enable managing these kinds of packages through `Composer`. If your extension depends on a `Bower` package, you can simply list the dependency in `composer.json` like the following:

```
{
// package dependencies
"require": {
    "bower-asset/jquery": ">=1.11.*"
}
}
```

So:

```
bower install materialize
```

More Information (`Yii2's` Official Document): **[Bower and NPM Assets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#bower-npm-assets)**

---

It might also be remarkable that, you can define new `Asset Bundle` for your app, so, there is no need to modify `AppAsset` class. To create your own `Asset Bundle` check the following links:

**[Defining Asset Bundles](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#defining-asset-bundles)** and **[Using Asset Bundles](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#using-asset-bundles)**

---

If you want to Disable `bootstrap` or `JQuery` from your app, you can check the following link:

**[Yii2 disable Bootstrap Js, JQuery and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734385/yii2-disable-bootstrap-js-jquery-and-css/26734892#26734892)**

Comment: change `>=1.11.*` to `>=1.11.0`
former throws an UnexpectedValueException

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Materialize for Yii2](https://macgyer.github.io/yii2-materializecss/) package.This repo provides an alternative to Bootstrap by implementing Materialize into Yii2.

Other alternative extensions are [1](https://github.com/webmaxx/yii2-materialize) & [2](https://github.com/tuyakhov/yii2-materialize).