# Custom Bootstrap 4 css and asset management in Yii2

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, yii2

I've installed the [yii2-bootstrap4](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4) extension in yii2-advanced and I've added a customized css file (`custom.css`) re-compiling Bootstrap source with Sass.

Then I've added `custom.css` to `frontend/web/css` and I've modified `frontend/assets/AppAsset.php` as follows:

```php
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/custom.css',
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

I obtained the result I wanted, but I noticed that the `<head>...</head>` of my pages contains the following:

```php
<link href="/yii2-advanced/frontend/web/assets/1758a11a/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/yii2-advanced/frontend/web/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/yii2-advanced/frontend/web/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
```

And:

- `[...]/css/bootstrap.css` contains the original Bootstrap 4 css
- if I delete that first entry from the DOM (via Devtools) the web pages are not
  affected.

**Questions**

1. Is this the correct way to replace the Bootstrap 4 css file in Yii2?
2. Is there a way to prevent the loading of `[...]/css/bootstrap.css`?

Comment: you can remove from your $depends 'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset', but i think it remove also the js file

Comment: @Sfili_81 If I remove `'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset'` the website stops working as expected. In that case, for some reason, the first entry in the `head` section is loaded last, so both `custom.css` and `site.css` get overridden.

Comment: Maybe this cah nelp you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734385/yii2-disable-bootstrap-js-jquery-and-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734385/yii2-disable-bootstrap-js-jquery-and-css)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yii2 disable Bootstrap Js, JQuery and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734385/yii2-disable-bootstrap-js-jquery-and-css)

Comment: Yes it does, I put an extended explanation in an answer if that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting one of the answers of this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30468710/1630538) (suggested by @Sfili_81), I solved modifying `frontend/assets/AppAsset.php` as follows:

```php
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/custom.css',
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset',
    ];

    public function init(){
        parent::init();
        // resetting BootstrapAsset to not load own css files
        \Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles['yii\\bootstrap4\\BootstrapAsset'] = [
            'css' => [],
            //'js' => []
        ];
    }
}
```

Now the css files included in the `<head>` section are only these ones:

```html
<link href="/yii2-advanced/frontend/web/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/yii2-advanced/frontend/web/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I would rather add these setting in the config.

Comment: In `frontend/config/main.php`? How?